# LINQ to return elements based on match with child elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I hope the title makes some sense.

I'm trying to generate a LINQ query that returns all elements of a child object's child object when they don't match with a property on the parent element.

Hopefully, I haven't lost you with that description. I think a concrete example might help to explain what I'm trying to do.

I have three classes and an enum:

```
public class Studio
{
    public int StudioId { get; set; }
    public string StudioName { get; set; }
    public Style Style { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Designer> Designers { get; set; }
}

public class Designer
{
    public int DesignerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int StudioId { get; set; }

    public virtual Studio Studio { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int DesignerId { get; set; }
    public Style ProductStyle { get; set; }

    public virtual Designer Designer { get; set; }
}

public enum Style { Classic, Preppy, Modern, Punk, Goth }
```

Each studio has its overall `Style`, and each `Product` has its own style. There are circumstances when a `Product` may shown at a `Studio` with a mismatched style philosophy.

Can I generate a `LINQ` query to return an `IEnumerable<Product>` containing all `Products` at a `Studio` that are a mismatch?

I've created a triple nested loop that works, but I was hoping for some help converting it into a LINQ statement (using the dot notation):

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProductsWithOutsideStyles(Studio studio)
{
    List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

    foreach (Studio s in StudioContext.Studios.Where(s => s == studio))
    {
        foreach(Designer d in s.Designers)
        {
            foreach(Product p in d.Products)
            {
                if (p.ProductStyle != s.Style)
                    products.Add(p);
            }
        }
    }

    return products;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the products belonging to a `Studio` through the navigation properties you've set up. Then it's easy to check for mismatches between `Product.ProductStyle` and `Studio.Style`:

```
from s in context.Studios
where s.StudioId == studio.StudioId
from d in s.Designers
from p in d.Products
where p.ProductStyle != s.Style
select p
```

By the way, you'll have to find the `Studio` by id. EF won't allow you to use the `studio` variable in the LINQ query.

Answer (score 2):

try :

```
 var products=studios.SelectMany(s => s.Designers
            .SelectMany(d => d.Products.Where(p => p.ProductStyle != s.Style)))
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the SQL-Style LINQ syntax with multiple `from` statements to create a query using "nested" lists

(Equivalent to the `.SelectMany()` extension method)

```
var products =
        from s in StudioContext.Studios.Where(s => s == studio)
        from d in s.Designers
        from p in d.Products
        where p.ProductStyle != s.Style
        select p;
```

The extension methods are valid too; but for nested lists I personally find SQL-style syntax to be a lot clearer (more readable) for expressing your intent.    When there are multiple levels of nesting, `.SelectMany` can be slightly less clear.